# Making an OAuth connection using native iOS classes

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, restkit

Ok, so this is a generic question. I have been using RestKit to make connections to OAuth and other web services. It really works great. And as we know there are several other 3rd party frameworks available too.

But, is it possible to fetch data from an OAuth web service using just the classes provided by native iOS frameworks (NSURLConnection, etc.).

I know it is, but then what makes it so difficult that almost everyone rather goes for something like RestKit. **If I want to write all the code by myself, how do I go about it. Which classes to use, what things to consider, any sample codes to refer, etc.**

PS - I had really tried to look around on the net for this before, but there wasn't any conclusive write-up available. 
As you would know, in spite of the tremendous convenience they provide there are some obvious things to consider while using a 3rd party library. Changes are frequent, you do not know when it might be decommissioned. And most importantly you would want to know every line of visible code that is there in your project.

Answer (score 0):

OAuth occurs over the network, passing a request and receiving a response indicating what needs to happen next.  So, given that, use NSURLConnection to send a request, and implement the delegate methods to listen for the response or failure, and potentially send more requests.

It can be daunting if you're first getting into OAuth, because the method calls back-and-forth seem overly complicated.  I'd suggest getting a simple OAuth library (a /very/ simple OAuth library), and trace through that code.